# how to show an event happened between two dates in R

Tags: r, date, intervals

My question seems simple and I hope it is.

I have a dataframe that has the date of diagnosis of a disease, a binary variable indicating which drug the patient was on (or exposed and unexposed group), a start and stop date for the drug, and an overall stop date.

```
ID    Diag_date    Treatment    End.date    Drug.start    drug.end
1        NA           0         15/03/2002   01/01/2002    01/02/2002
1        NA           1         15/03/2002   01/02/2002    01/03/2002
1        NA           0         15/03/2002   01/03/2002    NA
2    01/04/2002       1         01/05/2002   01/01/2015    01/02/2002
2    01/04/2002       0         01/05/2002   01/02/2002    01/03/2002
2    01/04/2002       0         01/05/2002   01/03/2002    NA
```

As you can see the date of diagnosis is non time-varying, but the drug start and stop dates are.

Preferably I want an answer to two questions:

1.) How do i transfer the overall `End.date` to the final `drug.end` for each `ID`?

2.) How do I create a binary column that shows if the diagnosis date occurs in the interval between `Drug.start` and `Drug.end`?

I wish my final data to look like the following:

```
ID    Diag_date    Treatment    End.Date     Drug.start    Drug.end    Event
1        NA           0         15/03/2002   01/01/2002    01/02/2002   0
1        NA           1         15/03/2002   01/02/2002    01/03/2002   0
1        NA           0         15/03/2002   01/03/2002    15/03/2002   0 
2    01/04/2002       1         01/05/2002   01/01/2015    01/02/2002   0
2    01/04/2002       0         01/05/2002   01/02/2002    01/03/2002   0
2    01/04/2002       0         01/05/2002   01/03/2002    01/05/2002   1
```

Not everyone has a diagnosis date because not everyone in the sample had the disease.  The code I wrote is the following:

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   if ((df$Diag_date[i] >= df$Drug.start[i]) && ( df$Diag_date[i] <= df$Drug.stop[i])) {
df$Event[i] <- 1
} else {
df$Event[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

the error i get when I run this code is:

```
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your input.  I already marked the answer I used, but all of them were very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_each(funs(as.Date(., '%d/%m/%Y')), matches('start|end|date')) %>%
     mutate(drug.end= as.Date(ifelse(is.na(drug.end), End.date, 
                         drug.end),origin='1970-01-01'),
    Event= as.integer((Diag_date >= Drug.start & Diag_date<=drug.end) & 
                        !is.na(Diag_date))) #%>%
    #mutate_each(funs(format(., '%d/%m/%Y')), matches('start|end|date'))
 #    ID  Diag_date Treatment   End.date Drug.start   drug.end Event
 #1  1       <NA>         0 2002-03-15 2002-01-01 2002-02-01     0
 #2  1       <NA>         1 2002-03-15 2002-02-01 2002-03-01     0
 #3  1       <NA>         0 2002-03-15 2002-03-01 2002-03-15     0
 #4  2 2002-04-01         1 2002-05-01 2015-01-01 2002-02-01     0
 #5  2 2002-04-01         0 2002-05-01 2002-02-01 2002-03-01     0
 #6  2 2002-04-01         0 2002-05-01 2002-03-01 2002-05-01     1
```

As @David Arenburg mentioned, it is better to keep the 'date' columns as the 'Date' class.  If you need it in the 'character' format, just uncomment the last line and run it.

NOTE: Removed the `group_by` as it was not needed

Answer (score 4):

Her's a possible `data.table` equivalent

```
library(data.table)

# Converting to dates
Dates <- names(df)[c(2, 4:6)]
setDT(df)[, (Dates) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), .SDcols = Dates] 

# First question
df[is.na(drug.end), drug.end := End.date] 

# Second question
df[Diag_date >= Drug.start & Diag_date <= drug.end, Event := 1L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Akrun's answer suffices for the problem in hand. Suggesting a more straight forward code.

```
A <- read.table("clipboard", header = T)
Dates <- c("Diag_date", "End.date", "Drug.start", "drug.end")


A[,Dates] <- lapply(A[,Dates],function(x) as.Date(x, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
A$drug.end[is.na(A$drug.end)] <- as.character(A$End.date[is.na(A$drug.end)])
A$Event <- as.numeric((A$Diag_date >= A$Drug.start & A$Diag_date<=A$drug.end) & !is.na(A$Diag_date))
```