# Determine presence and extent of overlapping date ranges by ID number - two data frames

Tags: r, data.table, desctools

I have two data frames as follows. They are of unequal length:

```
library(lubridate)

id <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9,
    10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 5451396, 5451396, 5451396, 5451396, 5451396)
admDt <- ymd(c("2000-02-24", "2000-04-30", "2000-06-06", "2001-01-29", "2004-06-10", "2001-05-21",
           "2000-01-25", "2000-04-18", "2000-01-14", "1991-10-06", "1992-02-25", "2000-05-17",
           "2003-06-06", "2009-02-16", "2000-01-23", "2000-03-10", "2000-04-05", "2000-06-16",
           "2000-07-04", "2000-07-27", "2001-01-19", "2002-08-16", "2002-09-19", "2004-04-17",
           "2005-08-02", "2005-09-21", "2006-07-10", "2000-02-24", "2000-05-05", "2000-08-29",
           "2001-01-24", "2000-01-27", "2000-03-09", "2000-04-15", "2000-03-20", "2002-11-13",
           "2000-06-28", "2000-07-02", "2000-06-13", "1999-12-27", "2008-09-10", "2000-04-09",
           "2000-06-01", "2002-11-25", "2006-08-04", "2006-10-07"))
sepDt <- ymd(c("2000-02-25", "2000-05-25", "2000-06-06", "2001-02-15", "2004-07-12", "2001-06-01",
           "2000-01-31", "2000-04-20", "2000-01-31", "1991-11-07", "1992-03-26", "2000-05-31",
           "2003-06-17", "2009-02-23", "2000-03-06", "2000-03-17", "2000-04-06", "2000-06-28",
           "2000-07-17", "2000-07-31", "2002-04-19", "2002-09-11", "2003-05-06", "2004-05-03",
           "2005-08-31", "2006-05-29", "2009-06-19", "2000-03-09", "2000-05-06", "2000-09-12",
           "2001-01-24", "2000-02-15", "2000-03-17", "2000-04-16", "2000-04-20", "2002-12-05",
           "2000-07-27", "2000-08-15", "2000-06-22", "2000-02-12", "2008-09-17", "2000-05-26",
           "2000-08-29", "2003-02-24", "2006-09-22", "2006-11-10"))
adm <- data.frame(id, admDt, sepDt)

id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 5451396)
birthDt <- ymd(c("1971-07-22", "1982-08-09", "1976-01-30", "1972-02-03", "1958-05-26", "1979-05-24",
             "1971-11-03", "1980-02-05", "1978-06-08", "1969-10-14", "1962-01-01", "1977-03-09",
             "1952-01-24", "1974-12-16", "1956-05-05", "1963-07-16"))
dxDt <- ymd(c("2000-02-24", "2000-04-30", "2000-03-03", "2000-01-31", "2000-06-20", "2000-12-13",
          "2000-05-14", "2000-01-23", "2000-03-09", "2000-02-15", "2000-05-01", "2000-06-30",
          "2000-08-15", "2000-06-22", "2000-01-27", "2000-06-01"))
admPreDx <- c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes","Yes", "Yes", "Yes",
          "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")
admPreDxNbr <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
admPreDxDur <- c(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 19, 20, 2, 31, 9, 31, 25)
admPostDx <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No",
           "No", "Yes", "Yes")
admPostDxNbr <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3)
admPostDxDur <- c(1, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 31, 0, 6, 0, 27, 0, 0, 16, 31)
admDx <- data.frame(id, birthDt, dxDt, admPreDx, admPreDxNbr, admPreDxDur, admPostDx, admPostDxNbr,
                admPostDxDur)


> head(adm)
  id      admDt      sepDt
1  1 2000-02-24 2000-02-25
2  2 2000-04-30 2000-05-25
3  2 2000-06-06 2000-06-06
4  2 2001-01-29 2001-02-15
5  2 2004-06-10 2004-07-12
6  3 2001-05-21 2001-06-01

> head(admDx)
  id    birthDt       dxDt admPreDx admPreDxNbr admPreDxDur admPostDx admPostDxNbr admPostDxDur
1  1 1971-07-22 2000-02-24       No           0           0       Yes            1            1
2  2 1982-08-09 2000-04-30       No           0           0       Yes            1           25
3  3 1976-01-30 2000-03-03       No           0           0        No            0            0
4  4 1972-02-03 2000-01-31      Yes           1           6        No            0            0
5  5 1958-05-26 2000-06-20       No           0           0        No            0            0
6  6 1979-05-24 2000-12-13       No           0           0        No            0            0
```

The actual datasets range from 10,000 to 1,000,000+ rows.

Each row in `adm` refers to a discrete hospital admission. Note: `id` is the patient's ID number, while `admDt` and `sepDt` refer to the admission and discharge dates, respectively. Some patient's have multiple admissions.

Each row in `admDx` refers to a single patient: `id` is the patient's ID number (consistent with that provided in `adm`), while `birthDt` and `dxDt` are the patient's birth and diagnosis dates, respectively.

I am conducting some longitudinal / time series analyses and would like to determine whether patients were or were not hospitalised during different time periods pre- and post- diagnosis. For the sake of brevity, this question is concerned with the one month before and after diagnosis. Ideally, I would like to:

- Create a dichotomous variable ("Yes" / "No"), indicating whether a given patient spent time in hospital during the time period (i.e., I am not concerned if they were admitted before the onset of the time period or if they were discharged after the offset of the time period)
- Calculate the number of times each patient was in hospital during the time period
- Calculate the duration (number of days) each patient was in hospital during the time period

I have reviewed a number of posts over several days (e.g., [R Time periods overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606875/r-time-periods-overlapping), [Join dataframes by id and overlapping date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542811/join-dataframes-by-id-and-overlapping-date-range), [how to show an event happened between two dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262707/how-to-show-an-event-happened-between-two-dates-in-r?rq=1)); however, none of them seem to combine the three aspects I am interested in (calculating time between overlapping dates; multiple data frames; by "group" [or individual]).

I am new to R and have had little experience with loops and more advanced formulae. It seems that it may be possible to use `foverlaps`, `lubridate`, or `%overlaps%` from the `"DescTools"` package; however, I am unsure how to construct the relevant formulae.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT #1:**

While @sirallen's suggestions worked for the specific time period in the example provided, `sum(pmin(dxDt, sepDt) - pmax(admDt, dxDt)), by = "id"` returned inaccurate values in my real dataset (e.g., patients with multiple admissions of duration one day ["2000-01-25" - "2000-01-26"] reportedly spent zero days in hospital. This seems strange to me, since the code seems to be be used to answer similar examples. *Does this issue relate to the fact that I have several overlapping date ranges for those patients?* Further, as noted by @sirallen, the code did not highlight when patients had one or more than one admission during the time period.

The code below provided a more direct route to the first two parts of my question, by determining a) whether a patient spent time in hospital and b) the number of admissions:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(adm)
setDT(admDx)[, (4:9) := NULL]

#Period bounds
admDx[, `:=`(dxDtN1 = dxDt %m-% months(1), dxDtP1 = dxDt %m+% months(1))]

#Hospitalised in the month preceding diagnosis
admDx <- adm[admDx, on = .(id, admDt < dxDt, sepDt > dxDtN1), .N, by = .EACHI]
admDx[, `:=` (admPreDx = factor(ifelse(N > 0, "Yes", "No")))]
```

However, the pmin / pmax code still does not work, returning negative values:

```
admDx[, `:=` (birthDt = birthDt, dxDt = dxDt, dxDtN1 = dxDt %m-% months(1), dxDtP1 = dxDt %m+% months(1))]
admDx[, `:=` (admPreDxDur=as.numeric(sum(pmin(dxDt, adm$sepDt) - pmax(dxDtN1, adm$admDt)))), by = "id"]
admDx <- select(admDx, admPreDx, N, admPreDxDur)


> head(admDx)
   admPreDx N admPreDxDur
1:       No 0      -28573
2:       No 0      -27160
3:       No 0      -28366
4:      Yes 1      -29357
5:       No 0      -26701
6:       No 0      -28044
```

**EDIT #2**

After testing additional cases, it seems that the issue re: pmin / pmax may relate to the use of `>` vs `>=`: when `>` is used, the correct `Dur` value is returned; however, when `>=` is used, `Dur` returns a value of 0.

How might this code be adapted to enable me to calculate the number of days up to, and including, the diagnosis date?

Comment: Instead of describing your expected output, show it (make sure it reflects your examples)

Comment: @Sotos Thanks for the feedback. I have included the expected output in the second data frame

Comment: If you want to include the diagnosis date, just add `+ (dxDt <= sepDt)` for preDx (`+ (dxDt >= admDt)` for postDx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with [non-equi joins](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable) in `data.table` (>=v1.9.8):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(adm)
setDT(admDx)[, (4:9):= NULL]

# period bounds
admDx[, `:=`(dxDtLo=dxDt-31, dxDtHi=dxDt+31)]

# hospitalized pre-dxnosis?
admDx = adm[, .(id, admDt, sepDt, dxDt=admDt, dxDtLo=sepDt)][admDx,
  on=.(id, dxDt < dxDt, dxDtLo > dxDtLo)]
admDx[, admPreDx:= as.numeric(!is.na(admDt))]
admDx[, `:=`(admPreDxNbr=sum(admPreDx), admPreDxDur=as.numeric(
  sum(pmin(dxDt,sepDt) - pmax(admDt,dxDtLo)))), by='id']
admDx[, c('admDt','sepDt'):= NULL]

# hospitalized post-dxnosis?
admDx = adm[, .(id, admDt, sepDt, dxDtHi=admDt, dxDt=sepDt)][admDx,
  on=.(id, dxDtHi < dxDtHi, dxDt > dxDt)]
admDx[, admPostDx:= as.numeric(!is.na(admDt))]
admDx[, `:=`(admPostDxNbr=sum(admPostDx), admPostDxDur=as.numeric(
  sum(pmin(sepDt,dxDtHi) - pmax(dxDt,admDt)))), by='id']
admDx[, c('admDt','sepDt'):= NULL]

admDx[is.na(admDx)] = 0
admDx = unique(admDx)[, c('dxDtLo','dxDtHi'):= NULL]

> admDx
#          id       dxDt    birthDt admPreDx admPreDxNbr admPreDxDur admPostDx admPostDxNbr admPostDxDur
#  1:       1 2000-02-24 1971-07-22        0           0           0         1            1            1
#  2:       2 2000-04-30 1982-08-09        0           0           0         1            1           25
#  3:       3 2000-03-03 1976-01-30        0           0           0         0            0            0
#  4:       4 2000-01-31 1972-02-03        1           1           6         0            0            0
#  5:       5 2000-06-20 1958-05-26        0           0           0         0            0            0
#  6:       6 2000-12-13 1979-05-24        0           0           0         0            0            0
#  7:       7 2000-05-14 1971-11-03        0           0           0         1            1           14
#  8:       8 2000-01-23 1980-02-05        0           0           0         1            1           31
#  9:       9 2000-03-09 1978-06-08        1           1          14         0            0            0
# 10:      10 2000-02-15 1969-10-14        1           1          19         1            1            8
# 11:      11 2000-05-01 1962-01-01        1           1          20         0            0            0
# 12:      12 2000-06-30 1977-03-09        1           1           2         1            1           27
# 13:      13 2000-08-15 1952-01-24        1           1          31         0            0            0
# 14:      14 2000-06-22 1974-12-16        1           1           9         0            0            0
# 15:      15 2000-01-27 1956-05-05        1           1          31         1            1           16
# 16: 5451396 2000-06-01 1963-07-16        1           1          25         1            1           31
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have had some difficulty with the pmin / pmax aspect of the code. What impact would the unique filter have on the Nbr and Dur columns?

Comment: Can you update your sample data w an id for which the above code fails? thanks. I think my code will generate duplicate rows when there are multiple admissions; `unique` will get rid of those

Comment: Sure thing! I'll get onto it now

Comment: I added an additional case to the dataset. My apologies - once I added the case, I realised I obtained different results depending on whether the start / end dates of the time periods (e.g., admDt, dxDt) overlapped. I do not understand why that subtle different would impact pmin / pmax; the two aspects of the code seem to be independent...

Comment: I modified the answer to correctly account for multiple admissions. (Turns out the single-operation join/assign did not work as I expected and only picked up the first hospital stay -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421640/assignment-with-data-table-join-operation-multiple-matches/.) As for the case you added, it looks like there is still only one stay within the 1-month period, so `admPostDxDur` should be 31... ?

Comment: The join is more convoluted now bc of the way names/values are inherited in the result -- see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1807. So `dxDt < dxDt, dxDtLo > dxDtLo` actually means `admDt < dxDt, sepDt > dxDtLo`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for your patience!