# Assignment with data.table join operation, multiple matches

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables:

```
dt1 = data.table(a=c('a','b'))
dt2 = data.table(a=c('a','b','b'))
```

Merging `dt1[dt2, on='a']` gives

```
   a
1: a
2: b
3: b
```

so when I perform the operation `dt1[dt2, on='a', c:= 1]` I expect

```
   a c
1: a 1
2: b 1
3: b 1
```

But instead I get

```
   a c
1: a 1
2: b 1
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

We need to use

```
dt2[dt1, c := 1, on = "a"]
dt2
#   a c
#1: a 1
#2: b 1
#3: b 1
```

If we are not interested in changing the initial dataset 'dt1', then

```
dt1[dt2, c(.SD, c= 1), on = 'a']
#   a c
#1: a 1
#2: b 1
#3: b 1
```

---

The problem in the OP's approach is that after the join, the assignment (`:=`) happens in the first dataset ('dt1') and it has only 2 rows, so, the assigned values will be also be in those 2 rows instead of 3 rows.  One option is to assign it to the second dataset (as showed in the first method) or we create a new dataset by concatenating a new column 'c'.

Comment: You say "after the join", but it sounds like the assignment happens before the join -- is that right?

Comment: @sirallen It is based on the join, for ex. `a1 <- data.table(a = 1:3);  b1 <- data.table(a = 2:4);a1[b1,  c:= 1,on = 'a']`.  You can see the difference in this approach and the `a1[b1, c(.SD, c = 1), on = 'a']`